# angular 2 change color row by click button

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a new in Angular.

Have a component:

```
export class ManageClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  users : CUser[] = [];
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
  }
   selectedSert : CUser;
   selectedSert:CUser[] = [];
  // @Input() cUser = CUser;
  // private cUser: any;
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.initialiseData();
  }

  private initialiseData() {

    this.httpService.getData().subscribe((data: Response) => this.users = data.json());
  }

  public sellSert (sert) {

    this.selectedSert = sert;
  }
```

and html:

```
  <tbody>
  <tr  *ngFor="let sert of users let ind = index">
    <td>{{sert.Id }}</td>
    <td>{{sert.buyDate}}</td>
    <td>
      <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
          <button class="dropdown-item">Сертификат</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item">Абонент</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{sert.summSert}}</td>
    <td>{{sert.endSert}}</td>
    <td>
      <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Действия</button>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
          <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="sellabonement(sert)">Change</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="sellSert(sert)" [class.selected]= "sert == selectedSert">SellAll</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I want to click the button SellAll and the row have to change the color, but when I push the button next row, the previous color standed the same it was, but I needn't the change color.

Comment: Instead of adding a CSS class to the row (tr) when the sert is the selected sert, you added a CSS class to the button inside the dropdown. Also, you defined the same field twice in your class, and your ngFor syntax is incorrect.

Comment: but when i add like this <tr  *ngFor="let sert of users let ind = index" [class.selected]= "sert == selectedSert"> the color dosen't save of the row